# How to know Apache2 modules usage statistics?

Tags: apache

Due to high memory & CPU usage for instances, I wonder if there's any way to get the statistics of Apache2 module usage (e.g. count on enabled module calls from http requests) so I could disable modules not being used. For example, suppose I have an instance with following Apache2 module enabled:

```
mod_expire
mod_rewrite
mod_proxy
mod_ssl
mod_status
....
```

The expected output (might be a static log or in real time; all ok):

```
From 2014/09/29 07:54:00 UTC+8

777777 mod_expire
555555 mod_rewrite
222222 mod_proxy
11     mod_ssl
33333  mod_status
....
```

Comment: I think you essentially need to _"profile Apache module performance"_. Try a google search for that and you might get some information or at least some good ideas on how to reduce the cpu load.

Comment: @ivy_lynx: I thank for your suggestion, but don't think that is a quantitative analysis approach.